# Can we upload aritfacts (.jar/.zip) created as part of jenkins pipeline to Azure Devops?

Tags: java, jenkins, azure-devops, devops, pvcs

I am working on a project which needs me to migrate the storage of artifacts from PVCS to Azure Devops. (Problem statement was provided like that)

**Current Setup:**

The Jenkins Pipeline takes a master.xls file from a folder created (unique for each build number) in PVCS and based on the data manually entered into master.xls, it interacts with Pega DB and creates an Artifact (Rules.Zip).

To interact with the PEGA DB, the Jenkins job executes few Java programs and executes a few batch and ant scripts. The ant scripts produce the artifacts.

Finally it stores that artifact in the same PVCS folder created initially with an empty master.xls file.

Jenkins is interacting with PVCS usling PCLI commands which will be executed from Java programs run by Jenkins jobs.

**Required Setup:**

The PVCS needs to be replaced with Azure Devops, i.e. the Jenkins Pipeline should be able to do the following:

1. Create a folder in Azure Devops with an empty master.xls
2. After master.xls is updated manually, The pipeline should be interacting with Pega DB as usual and store the artifact thus created into Azure Devops.

I am pretty new to Azure Devops. Kindly help me understand if the said requirement is possible and If so, how can that be achieved. A list of abstract steps would be of great help. I will work on them.

Comment: Look at universal artifact feeds.

Comment: @Manish Golla Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?Could you store the artifacts now? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **J[enkins Download Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/jenkins-download-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task** in azure devops pipeline that you can make use of to download the artifacts from Jenkins pipeline to azure devops pipeline.

First you need to create Jenkins [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) in your azure devops project.
Open the **Service connections** page under the **project settings** page, and select **New service connection** and choose **Jenkins**.
[image]

Then you can initialize a empty [azure repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/code-with-git?view=azure-devops). Click the + beside your project name and select **New Repository**

[image]

Then you need to create a [build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser%2Ctfs-2018-2#get-your-first-run), selecting your azure repo as the location of your source code. Below example is in classic view(Choose **use the classic editor** to create a classic view build pipepline).

[image]

Then choose **start with an empty job** to create a empty build pipeline
[image]

When your pipeline is initiated you can add  Jenkins Download Artifacts task to download the artifacts from Jenkins pipeline.
And you can add command line task to [run git command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-scripts-to-run-git-commands) in your pipeline to commit and push the artifacts to your azure repo.

[image]

You can also add **[Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)** task to publish the artifacts to azure devops pipeline server.

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/) is more information about how to integrate Jenkins with azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting you want the file stored in version control... Right? Cause, like @DanielMann suggests, you can attach the file as a Build Artifact or as a package in an Artifact feed. You can use the Azure CLI + DevOps extension to interact with the package feeds:

[image]

If you want to store it in version control... What kind of version control has been selected in Azure DevOps, Git or TFVC?

If **TFVC**, you can use tf.exe from jenkins or this [set of tasks for Azure Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks)  to store the artefact in TFVC.

If **Git**, you can use git.exe in both jenkins and Azure Pipelines to add, commit and push the changes to the Git repository.

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing , Yes I want the .jar file to be stored in Azure Repos. Wanted to know If that is possible. If it is not , Is there any other place I can store the Artifacts in Azure ? This artifact is not produces by the azure pipeline. It is created by a jenkins pipeline on the machine where master is running.

Comment: Azure Repos is Git or TFVC, there is commandline tooling for both. The Artifact feeds each explain how to push data into them and offer links to the respective tooling.

Comment: Thank you so much @jessehouwing . I will look into it.

Comment: If you have more specific questions either edit this question and send me a ping, or close this question, ask a new one and send me a ping.